# How can I square every element in an n by n numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't want any for loop and was wondering if there is a function I can use.

Comment: Element-wise squaring?

Comment: Yes. [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] becomes [[1,4,9],[2,9,16]]

Comment: @Jobs I think you mean that list becomes  `[[1,4,9],[4,9,16]]`

Comment: Yes - you are right. @AntonProtopopov

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations

Answer (score 6):

If A was the numpy array, I would just type in A*A.

Answer (score 5):

As K. Tom suggested you can do `A * A` you can also do `A ** 2`

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1,2,3])

print array * array #[1 4 9]
print array ** 2    #[1 4 9]
```

Comment: I definitely did not know that! Thanks.

Comment: The only thing to take care of is the type. `a = np.array([[100, 200], [50, 150]], dtype=np.uint8); a*a` will overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.square`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-14LtzOzLAhXnIJoKHUQcC_IQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.1%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.square.html&usg=AFQjCNGq2ccCBDJwodRY7EA75dNazQFJEQ&bvm=bv.118443451,d.bGs) or [`np.power`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwisnJDzzOzLAhXCE5oKHUlqAiUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.power.html&usg=AFQjCNGN2kR-HxbHF-3HCN4ANNd8H7jtAA&bvm=bv.118443451,d.bGs):

```
l =  [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]

In [5]: np.power(l, 2)
Out[5]:
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [ 4,  9, 16]], dtype=int32)

In [6]: np.square(l)
Out[6]:
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [ 4,  9, 16]], dtype=int32)
```